# Extract text from a column

Tags: sql-server

I've got a column 'Title' and it holds values similar to this text here

> HotelBeds SLU: Refugi Dels Isards Hotel in Pas de la Casa, Andorra (4 nights)

I'd want to select anything that comes after the colon (:) and exclude anything after the comma.

I tried this:

```
Select SUBSTRING(title,
            CHARINDEX(':',title)+1,
          CHARINDEX(',',title)
          -CHARINDEX(':',title)-1) HotelName from booking_tbl
```

I see this error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its exactly as the error says? The values you are passing to `sub-string` are wrong. Select the `charindex` values without using the `sub-string` and you'll soon work out what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this using [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This function searches for one character expression inside a second character expression, returning the starting position of the first expression if found.

**Syntax**

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Implementation

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max) = 'HotelBeds SLU: Refugi Dels Isards Hotel in Pas de la Casa, Andorra (4 nights)'
SELECT
  RTRIM(LEFT( @x , CHARINDEX(':',  @x ))) AS PartA,
  SUBSTRING( @x , CHARINDEX(':',  @x ) + 1, 8000) AS PartB
```

[db<>fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3860cc469acd9801f30d4a01ab346f4f)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the `,` or `:` as becuase some titles don't have `,` or `:` :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(title, CHARINDEX(':',title + ':') + 1, 
                 CHARINDEX(',', title + ',') - CHARINDEX(':',title + ':') 
                ) HotelName 
FROM booking_tbl bt;
```

You can either add `where` clause to avoid error :

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(',', tittle) > 0 AND
      CHARINDEX(':', title) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @str nvarchar(250)
set @str = 'HotelBeds SLU: Refugi Dels Isards Hotel in Pas de la Casa, Andorra (4nights)';
select ltrim(
 substring(
  @str, 
  charindex(':', @str) + 1, 
  charindex(',', @str) - (charindex(':', @str) + 1)
 )
)
```